# Should it be.... 'The day you become Mrs' or 'The day you became Mrs'?

Tags: verbs, tenses

I am looking to get something engraved and wondered if it should read 'the day you become Mrs' or 'the day you became'.

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I depends what you want it to mean. Do you want talk about the future or the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special lady you're giving it to will 'become Mrs' on the date you give it to her, but after that it will always be 'the day you became'. So since she'll be remembering that date, 'the day you became' will probably be better in the long run e.g.

> 06-06-14, the day you became Mrs X